# I keep getting Zombie Villagers at night - Minecraft PC 1.12.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So while I am working at night around my house I keep getting like one or two Zombie Villages around. Does that mean I have another village close by? I have searched thoroughly the immediate area around my spawn so I'm pretty sure there isn't a village close by. The closest village is more than 50 chunks away, and the next one is 60+ away.

So what gives? Is it normal for Zombie Villagers to just spawn out of nowhere EVERY NIGHT ? I know there is a slight chance for a zombie to spawn, but every night seems a bit odd.

So why am I getting zombies in my own house :D ?

Comment: This should probably be split into two questions. Why are zombie villagers spawning when there is no village around, and Why are mobs spawning at light levels greater than 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zombie villagers are a hostile mob that make up 5% of zombies that spawn in the Overworld. They will spawn just like normal zombies.  You can capture and heal them to get villagers at your house if you would like.

Quote from [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager):

> Zombie villagers also spawn naturally in the Overworld in the same conditions as a normal zombie.

Comment: Yea but I was wondering if it was something else causing me to see one of them every night. Legit every night for days and days :D

Comment: Oh, I see.  I see them in waves.  I will have streaks of days when I see them and streaks of days when I don't.  On a humorous note, generally if I am looking for one to capture, I can't find any.

Comment: THE MURPHY law :D If u need something it ain't there if u don't need it its always in your face